# Mootools - add variables to all draggable and droppable elements with .implement

Tags: javascript, class, drag-and-drop, mootools, expand

Im making a drag and drop system with mootools drag.move class, but i need all the draggable and droppable elements to have some extra variables and maybe add in a function or two. Ive researched on how to do this using .implement but Ive got no idea how to fit that into my code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){

 $$('#draggables DIV').makeDraggable({

droppables: $$('#droppables DIV'),

onEnter: function(draggable, droppable){
    droppable.setStyle('background', 'orange');
    droppable.setStyle('opacity', '0.4');
    snap_left = droppable.getStyle('left');
    snap_top = droppable.getStyle('top');   
    document.getElementById("slot").innerHTML=droppable.id;
},

onLeave: function(draggable, droppable){
    droppable.setStyle('background', null);
},

onDrop: function(draggable, droppable){

    if (droppable){
        droppable.setStyle('background', '');
        draggable.setStyle('left', snap_left );
        draggable.setStyle('top', snap_top );                   
    } else {
        draggable.setStyle('left', snap_left );
        draggable.setStyle('top', snap_top );
    }
}

 });

});
```

Is what I want posible using .implement? 

Can I add these things to all draggable and droppable elements?

ty in advance!

-Thaiscorpion

edit:
Ive tried adding options directly to the main class in the mootools library and tried accesing them from the onEnter event like this:

```
    onEnter: function(draggable, droppable){
```

`if (droppable.occupied){ //here is where im tryin to acces it, the default option is set to occupied: true
        droppable.setStyle('background', 'red');
        droppable.setStyle('opacity', '0.4');
        document.getElementById("slot").innerHTML=droppable.id;
    } else {
        droppable.setStyle('background', 'orange');
        droppable.setStyle('opacity', '0.4');
        snap_left = droppable.getStyle('left');
        snap_top = droppable.getStyle('top');   
        document.getElementById("slot").innerHTML=droppable.id;
    }



},`

but not getting anything to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use element storage.

```
draggable.store("occupied", true);
```

....

```
if (draggable.retrieve("occupied") === true) {

}
```

.... functions or anything can be stored per element

```
element.store("somekey", function() {
    element.toggleClass("foo");
});

element.retrieve("somekey").call(element);
```

and so forth.

to use Implement:

```
Element.implement({
    dragfoo: function() {
        this.set("drag", { });
        return this;
    }
});

// allows you:

$("someid").dragfoo();
```

though if you need storage, use storage and dont store properties on the actual element. mootools storage really uses an object hash table that's behind a closure. having proprietary element attributes/properties in IE can slow things down considerably in element access.